# Sum function to join three tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have three tables as descried below

```
Main_id | Main _name
--------+-----------
1       | A
2       | B

Sub_id | Sub_name  | Main_id   (foreign key from main table) 
-------+-----------+--------
11     | AA        | 1 
12     | AB        | 1
22     | BB        | 2

Transaction_ID  | Amount  | Sub_id  (foreign key from sub table)  
----------------+---------+---------
1               | 100     |  11
1               | 200     |  11
1               |  50     |  22
```

I want to have sum of transaction to every main account so it look like 
what is the SQL query to have this result every main id and it's total amount

```
Main_id | Total Amount
--------+---------------
1       | 300
2       |  50
```

What is the SQL query ?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Where is your query ?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`/`GROUP BY`.

Comment: The sub_ids in the third table do not match sub_ids in the second table. See: [SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) in w3schools.

Comment: @Olivier, I'd say that it just means that there's no transaction for SUB_ID = 12. That's not an *error* (from my point of view). **EDIT** Bah! Wrong data has been edited since your objection, didn't notice it in time. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Main_id, sum(Amount) "Total Amount"
from Table1 inner join Table2 using(Main_id)
            inner join Table3 using(Sub_id)
group by Main_id
order by 1;
```

> MAIN_ID Total Amount
>
> ---
>
> ```
>      1          300
>      2           50
> ```

Comment: can you write it without join keyword

Comment: A join of tables is required because Main_is is not a column of Table3.
We can us the old joining notation like this:

select Table1.Main_id, sum(Amount) "Total Amount"
from Table1, Table2, Table3
where Table1.Main_id = Table2.Main_id
and   Table2.Sub_id = Table3.Sub_id
group by Table1.Main_id
order by 1;